# How to wait 'for' loop for returning

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I know it is a simple, dumb question but it's been two days since I'm stuck on it.

Consider there is a function, managing creation of object type `Course` from some object type `UnsafeCourse`, like so:

```
Class Schedule {
    constructor() {
        this.courses = [];
    }

    sectionNeedsCourse(unsafeCourse) {
        this.courses.forEach(function (course, index, array) {
            if (course.couldBeRepresentedBy(unsafeCourse)) {
                return course;
            }
        }

        return new Course(unsafeCourse, [some additional parameters...]);
    }
}
```

As things in *node.js* works asynchronously, for loop is gone-through.

I tried different approaches with `Promise`s, didn't work.

```
sectionNeedsCourse(unsafeCourse) {  //->  Promise
    return new Promise (function (resolve) {
        new Promise(function (resolve) {
            this.courses.forEach(function (course, index, array) {
                if (course.couldBeRepresentedBy(unsafeCourse)) {
                    resolve(eachCourse);
                }
            });

            resolve(null);
        }).then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            if (result != null) {
                addCourse(unsafeCourse).then(function (result) {
                    resolve(result);
                });
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Also, is it a good practice to use multiple `Promise`s in same function?

Does it make heavy overhead?

Comment: Wait, you're `return`ing from within a `.forEach` callback? Looks like even your original code doesn't work like one might expect. What is exactly is *supposed* to happen?

Comment: @Bergi actually I put it in purpose of showing how it would be in such synchronous platform (that code was translated from Swift language)

Comment: It definitely is a bad practice to [use `new Promise`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) at all.

Comment: No dumb questions, only dumb answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any async method in your first example. `Array.forEach` is not a async function.
You just return the course inside of the callback of forEach, but you must return it directly in `sectionNeedsCourse`:

```
sectionNeedsCourse(unsafeCourse) {
    var course = this.courses.find(function(course){
      course.couldBeRepresentedBy(unsafeCourse) ? course : false;      
    });
    return course ? course : new Course(unsafeCourse, []);
}
```

As you can see, i also use `find` instead of `forEach`, because this is the logic you need here.

As requested here the same example a little bit shorter with an [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
sectionNeedsCourse(unsafeCourse) {
    var course = this.courses.find(course => {
      course.couldBeRepresentedBy(unsafeCourse) ? course : false;      
    });
    return course ? course : new Course(unsafeCourse, []);
}
```

Comment: What did you do with `=>` arrow?

Comment: This is called Arrorw function and was introduced with EcmaScript 6. I updated the example with a "normal" function instead.

Comment: Could you please add the former, I also want to learn that new syntax.